# Submit button styled as text - remove text indent in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Ive removed the background and border from a submit button so its styled as normal text. FF is fine but IE is indenting the text and I can't figure out how to remove this text indent.
Thanks

Update - Ive set the padding, margin and text-indent to 0 but no luck. Ill upload the site so I can post a link soon.

Update 2 - Ah, I just needed to add text-align:left;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add text-align:left;

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `text-indent: 0; padding: 0;` in your CSS?

posting some code may help, too.

Answer (score 1):

There's padding on the button in IE. Try setting the padding to 0.

```
.text-button
{
  padding: 0; /* remove padding */
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

// The button
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="text-button" />
```